# Jquery tabs not working on different domain

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

I have created a site for a client with jquery tabs, on my hosting they work fine

http://auto.nathanrobjohn.com

but on his hosting it just doesn't seem to want to work

http://www.modernandclassicautos.co.uk.php53-7.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/

I haven't changed anything at all.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Which elements are the 'tabs' you are referring to?

Comment: the tabs on the home page

Answer (score 0):

Run the console on Chrome, saw the next errors on the new hosting while on your hosting not:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.min.js:1 Uncaught
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery-ui.min.js:1 Uncaught
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < conditionizr.min.js:1 Uncaught
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < modernizr.min.js:1 Uncaught
>
> ReferenceError: conditionizr is not defined
>   www.modernandclassicautos.co.uk.php53-7.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/:43
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: Modernizr is not defined
>   scripts.js?ver=1.0.0:6

When I clicked on the link to the jquery's file - I think I've found the problem.
The difference between the two versions is the URL of the scripts.
On the one that works:

```
http://ajax.googleapi...
```

While on the other one:

```
//ajax.googleapi...
```

**UPDATE:**

Consider following the next 2 suggestions:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js?ver=1.9.1"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

(1)Add `http:` before the `//ajax` in the `src.

(2) Why are you loading this file twice? remove the second line.

**UPDATE 2**

I've noticed you also have the following code:
And the first js file does not exist on your server , therefore you see HTML - the HTML of the 404 page.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js?ver=1.9.1'>
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/ajax/libs/conditionizr.js/2.2.0/conditionizr.min.js?ver=2.2.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.2/modernizr.min.js?ver=2.6.2'></script>
```

Remove the first line. You're calling the same jquery script 3 times - not a good idea at all.

Hope it helped , update me if not.

Comment: There's no change as far as I can see. Have you uploaded it to the server?

Comment: yeah it has been uploaded to server

Comment: So how come I still see it without `http:` in the beginning?
Nope , still not updated... If you take a look at the `view source` there's `http://` before the `ajax.googleapis` in the `head`?

Comment: If its not showing - they are not there. ("view source can't lie :P")
This is what causing the errors and the nonfunctional tabs.

Comment: still not working for some reason my conditionizer and the others just show html in them?

Comment: I think I know what's the problem. There are more "calls" to those js files but this time to js files that not exist on the server (check out **UPDATE2** in my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Check the contents of your `jquery.min.js` and `jquery-ui.min.js` files. They appear to contain HMTL pages.